# Sitecore 10.3 with Sql Server compatibility

Tags: upgrade, sql-database

Believe Sitecore 10.3 compatible with MS Sql 2022 considers upward compatibility? If yes, do we need to run the database upgrade scripts provided by Sitecore?

Note: Sitecore Compatibility table does not contain MS Sql 2022.

Ref: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0087164
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore 10.3 requires **Microsoft SQL Server 2017 or later**. So if you are installing a fresh Sitecore 10.3 version with Microsoft SQL Server 2022 version, you don't need to run any upgrade script for that.

But if you are planning to upgrade your old Sitecore solution into Sitecore 10.3 then Yes, you need to run the script provided in the Sitecore Upgrade document.

You can refer to the Sitecore document for installing a new Sitecore instance or upgrading any Sitecore version to 10.3

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/103/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_103.aspx

Also if you get any error during installation, kindly ask a new question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @sumit. Old instance - 9.2 is also running under Sql 2022. I think in that case also, we do not need to run? Also, what about DB clean up as Sitecore move default items as Items As Resources file.

Comment: @Thamizh Yes you don't need to run. And for DB clean up, you should look into Sitecore recommendations for the upgrade process. You will get some steps to handle those items.